How to back up iPhone that shuts down every three minutes?
My Mom has an iPhone SE second generation with iOS 14.2. Last Thursday (4th July), the iPhone fell on the ground and since then it has shut down every three minutes. After looking at the panic log, the error that comes up is "no successful checkins from com.apple.thermalmonitord since load".
After looking on the internet, we found this thread on iFixit, Restarts every 3 minutes because of thermalmonitord, so it turns out that a sensor doesn't work anymore, and this causes the iPhone to shut down after three minutes.
We tried to back up the iPhone on a computer with iTunes, but since it shuts down every three minutes, the backup needs to restart every time. Is there any other way to back up the iPhone? There is about 60 GB to back up, including 44 GB for pictures.

Try: Sync photos to iCloud - that should be able to recover and continue after each restart. Other apps may be able to sync data to iCloud.
